# Ordering 2d/3d object behind other element

Tags: wpf, opencv, wpf-controls, emgucv, viewport3d

As you can see in [the link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/124973), I have two elements: first is *image* element which is taken from camera (using EmguCV) and the other one is *viewport3d* which renders 3d object. I also include 2d object (see the rectangle).

When I run my program I see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/124977).

Yes indeed, the object (hand) will be ordered in front of the image.

The question is how to order 2d/3d object behind the hand object? Is it possible to do it using single camera? Just like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRU6Ns0tBpQ).

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.

1. Use kinect depth map to find the distance of hand from camera.
2. Do image processing to detect hand and it's distance.

I think it will be difficult to directly blend WPF UI with camera image.
Try RenderTargetBitmap
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx